# How to write a web based GUI for a bash script?

Tags: git, bash, user-interface, web

I have a bash script on a server which is used to build a software project and then runs some scripts over it. Right now I need to access it via ssh and call it with a syntax like this: `./buildscript.sh branch_name` it then pulls the code from git and builds the branch given as the parameter.
What I want is to make this easier accessible via a web GUI where I might see a dropdown list of available branches and a button to start the build process.
My question is with which technology can I achieve something like this? And how to start maybe?

Im grateful for any hints or tips!
Thanks!

Comment: Can't you just use a PHP (or whatever web language you're into) web application which runs the bash script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the tips here! 
But I ended up using [websocketd](http://websocketd.com)
It's awesome simple and nice to use since you can just use std in and std out of a bash script as if it's directly accessed.

Answer (score 1):

You can look into continuous integration tools such as Jenkins (or [others](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_build_automation_software#Continuous_integration_tools)) which provide the ability to kick off builds, tests, and deployments either in response to certain events or on demand.

The tools do take some effort to set up, so you'll have to decide whether the the extra complexity is worth it for what you want to accomplish.